# Reevaluate formula calculation cell when using Sax parser of Apache-Poi

Tags: apache-poi, saxparser

Because of memory concern, we're using Sax parser approach of apache poi to read huge .xlsx excel files.
However, this approach seems to have an limitation at formula cells. It seems to read value from the 'cached formula value'.
I cannot find best solution to trigger recalculation to have updated value.
Does anyone face same problem? Thanks.

Comment: What's wrong with the values cached in the file by Microsoft Excel?

Comment: For some reasons, the value of formula cell is not trigger to recalculate. Then what we got is old value, is not up-to-date. Even Excel application has a option to force recalculation when opening. Another example is mentioned in apache poi document: http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/eval.html (Recalculation of Formulas)

Answer (score 1):

A general solution for this is probably very hard as the formula re-evaluation potentially needs to have random access to any cell in any sheet as formulas can reference them, something that you cannot do when using SAX.

You might be able to implement your own formula-evaluator which works with a number of restrictions on the type of formulas and references that are possible, but it is likely a bit of work to do.

See `XSSFFormulaEvaluator` for the implementation for .xlsx which heavily relies on the XSSFWorkbook/XSSFSheet/XSSFRow/XSSFCell classes.